# setOnClickListener for a button crashes the app

Tags: java, android

So, When I try to launch this application it crashes. However, it only crashes when I try to use the setOnClickListener. If I comment out that small section it runs just fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //textView.setText("Boop!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

OK Working code! I had to move super.onCreate up, and declair the textview inside the findviewbyID section. However, now it works as I intended. Thank you guys for the help! I just wanted to make something very basic for a date. xD you guys are a life saver.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText("Boop!");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**WORKING**

Comment: where is your logcat??? post it

Comment: You should check (in code as well) if the textView actually has any value. I suspect it didn't find any.

Comment: Please post your logCat.

Comment: it may be becoz you are initializing button before super method.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming because you are calling the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
after the `setContentView` and  then using the variables.

Reason that the error is not coming until you don't write onClicklister:
The variables textView and button are already null or in inconsistent state, but when you are writing the click listener, the variables are used and you are facing error.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `textView` as [`final`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A variable can be declared final. A final variable may only be assigned to once.

```
final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

so you cannot modify it.

You must get the view inside onclick method:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Boop!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, I moved the variable into the on-click listener like you showed. However, it still crashes.